# Is there such a thing as a writable VirtualPathProvider?

Tags: c#, virtualpathprovider

I'm looking at using VirtualPathProviders to abstract away the accessing of files on the filesystem so that this could be easily swapped out to work with other services such as Amazon S3.

Whilst this works really well for reading files, I was wondering if there is something similar that also supports writing? or would I have to create something myself like a WritableVirtualPathProvider?

Many thanks

Matt

Answer (score -1):

You could try Dokan http://dokan-dev.net/en/